# Add Firebase List of Object from DataSnapshot to Array

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have stored my **Images URLs on Firebase Database**, as I have been reading here it was the way to go.

Now I need to retrieve the **5 Picture Objects** form the List and put them into an array for later use.

So I add a SingleValueEvent to my Reference which is on **UserId Node** and get a DataSnapshot Object, which I check for null.
The problem is that even if I **only have a list of 5 Pictures** in my Database, when iterating on the DataSnapshot Object it **adds 19 Picture Objects** into the Array...

```
02-14 15:13:45.375 21952-21952/com.example I/EditProfileFragment:Picture Array : 19
```

What am I missing here?

**The Json looks like this:**

```
PicturesUrls {
 UserID {

  randomID{
   pictureName : "Main Picture"
   pictureUrl : "URL"
  }

  randomId
   pictureName : "Second Picture"
   pictureUrl : "URL"

  randomId {
   pictureName : "Third Picture"
   pictureUrl : "URL"
  }
 }
}
```

**Here is my Code:**

```
ArrayList<Object> mPicturesArray = new ArrayList<>();
....
....

mPicturesUrlRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot != null) {
                    addPicturesToArray(dataSnapshot);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });




private void addPicturesToArray(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Picture picture = child.getValue(Picture.class);
        mPicturesArray.add(picture);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "One Picture added : " + picture.getPictureName());
    }
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Picture Array : " + mPicturesArray.size());
}
```

Comment: please share your logcat

Comment: Logcat shows nothing, except that the picture Array size is 19

Comment: It will be hard to say much without seeing where `dataSnapshot` comes from. And it would probably also be useful to see the minimal JSON (as text please, no screenshot) that creates the problem. Please share the [minimum, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `except that the picture Array size is 19` I want to see it, please post it

Comment: Thanks, I have Edited the Original question

Comment: Log the size of `mPicturesArray` just before the dataSnapshot looping, make sure the result is `0`

Answer (score 0):

Hummm....

Ok so I have changed the **ArrayList** to a **HashMap** and things are working as expected now.
No idea why but...

Comment: HashMap is the only collection type that Firebase supports